# How and when should I use "By now"?

Tags: meaning

What does  "by now" stand for?

Where should I put it within a sentence? starting or finishing?
Is it right if I say "By now, I won't go to Melbourne"?

Comment: It's much like "by this time."  You might say something like, "If I haven't gone to Melbourne by now, I probably won't ever go," or "The train must be running late; we should have been to Melbourne by now."

Comment: "By now, I'd be in Melbourne... if I'd caught my train."

Answer (score 11):

To understand the phrase *by now*, I suggest starting with understanding the sense of *by* that is in use.  In this phrase, *by* indicates the end of a particular period of time.

> *I have to finish writing this answer **by midnight**.*
>
> *I expect the package to arrive **by tomorrow**.*

Of course *now* simply means the present moment, so *by now* means "a period of time ending at the present moment."

So no, it is not right to say *By now, I won't go to Melbourne* and I am not sure what you mean by that.

You can put *by now* at the beginning or at the end of a sentence.  It's a matter of what you want to emphasize. If we are on a train and it is now past the scheduled arrival time of the train in Melbourne, I could say:

> We should be in Melbourne by now. *(emphasizes where we should be)*
>
> By now we should be in Melbourne. *(emphasizes how much time has passed)*

I might say the first sentence if I know what time it is but do not know where we are (as is generally the case when I'm on a train).  The second is more of a complaint about how late the train is running when I know the schedule and I know we are a long way from Melbourne (and probably my destination is even farther away).

But these are not hard and fast distinctions. If I were upset about the train running late, I might use the first sentence to express my displeasure to the train conductor, even though I know where we are (different sense of *should*).

Comment: In your examples, why don't we know whether we're in Melbourne?  Are we on a train with the curtains drawn?  That's the only context in which those sentences make sense, as phrased.  Maybe you meant "we *should have been* in Melbourne by now" (counterfactual)?  Your sentences **do** make sense if we're talking about someone else (about whose whereabouts we can't be certain): "By now, *he* should be in Melbourne."

Comment: "We should be in Melbourne by now" is fine if "we" are actually on the train which is running late.